# How can i access to the values of the properties of an edge when using Apache AGE extension on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

In the following function, postgresql doesn't returned the results. In my opinion i can't access to the value of the properties.
I defined the edges like below:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$ 
    MATCH (a1:Airport),(a2:Airport) WHERE a1.iata_code='ANC' AND a2.iata_code='SEA' CREATE (a1)-[e:Flight{flight_number: 'N407DA', departure_time: 55200, arrival_time: 64800, distance: 1448}]->(a2) RETURN e 
$$) as (e agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$ 
    MATCH (a1:Airport),(a2:Airport) WHERE a1.iata_code='SEA' AND a2.iata_code='LAX' CREATE (a1)-[e:Flight{flight_number: 'N405KJ', departure_time: 63000, arrival_time: 70000, distance: 1448}]->(a2) RETURN e 
$$) as (e agtype);
```

And this is the full function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION age_graph.paircpath(
    origin text,
    edge text,
    destination text
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    city1 ag_catalog.agtype, 
    airport1 ag_catalog.agtype, 
    flight ag_catalog.agtype, 
    airport2 ag_catalog.agtype, 
    city2 ag_catalog.agtype
) 
LANGUAGE 'plpython3u'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
ROWS 1000
AS $function$
    import age
    import psycopg2

    def paircpath(origin, edge, destination):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", port="5432", dbname="postgres", user="postgres", password="13711992")
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                cursor.execute("SET search_path = ag_catalog, public, age_graph;")
                cursor.execute("LOAD 'age';")
                cursor.execute("GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ag_catalog TO postgres;")

                query = f"""SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$ 
                    MATCH (a)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c:City {{name: '{origin}'}})
                    MATCH (a:Airport)-[e:{edge}]->(b:Airport) 
                    MATCH (b)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c1:City {{name: '{destination}'}}) 
                    RETURN c, a, e, b, c1 
                $$) AS (city1 agtype, airport1 agtype, flight agtype, airport2 agtype, city2 agtype); """

                cursor.execute(query, ('age_graph',))
                paths = cursor.fetchall()

                for row in paths:
                    edges = row[2]
                    is_continuous = True
                    for i in range(len(edges) - 1):
                        arrival_time = edges[i].properties('arrival_time').value
                        departure_time = edges[i].properties('departure_time').value
                        next_departure_time = edges[i+1].properties('departure_time').value
                        if arrival_time < next_departure_time:
                            is_continuous = False
                            break
                    if is_continuous:
                        yield(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])


            except Exception as ex:
                print(type(ex), ex)

    for result in paircpath(origin, edge, destination):
        yield result

$function$;
```

I tried in different ways to reach to the values of the edge properties. but still after a month i couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a debug on this function. I noticed just one thing in the query:

```
MATCH (a)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c:City {{name: '{origin}'}})
```

Should this have two braces? I think it should only have one, this way:

```
MATCH (a)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c:City {name: '{origin}'})
```

If you can provide an error message, I can try to help you more. Alternatively, try using edges[i]['arrival_time'] or adding the properties on the return clause as such:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$ 
    MATCH (a)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c:City {name: '{origin}'})
    MATCH (a:Airport)-[e:{edge}]->(b:Airport) 
    MATCH (b)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c1:City {name: '{destination}'}) 
    RETURN c, a, e, b, c1, e.arrival_time, e.departure_time
$$) AS (city1 agtype, airport1 agtype, flight agtype, airport2 agtype, city2 agtype, arrival_time agtype, departure_time agtype);
```

References: [Apache AGE Python Samples](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/python/samples/apache-age-note.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

In Age, an `agtype` object representing an edge doesn't support the `.properties('property').value` method to access a property. You might need to use a cypher query to extract the properties you need.

In you `paircpath` function , you can modify your code to return properties directly. It will look something like:

```
query = f"""SELECT * FROM cypher('age_graph', $$ 
    MATCH (a)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c:City {{name: '{origin}'}})
    MATCH (a:Airport)-[e:{edge}]->(b:Airport) 
    MATCH (b)-[:LocatedAt*]->(c1:City {{name: '{destination}'}}) 
    RETURN c, a, e.departure_time, e.arrival_time, b, c1 
$$) AS (city1 agtype, airport1 agtype, departure_time integer, arrival_time integer, airport2 agtype, city2 agtype); """
```

Then, from your python code, you can access these properties directly:

```
for row in paths:
    edges = row[2]
    is_continuous = True
    for i in range(len(edges) - 1):
        arrival_time = edges[i][3]
        departure_time = edges[i][2]
        next_departure_time = edges[i+1][2]
        if arrival_time < next_departure_time:
            is_continuous = False
            break
    if is_continuous:
        yield(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
```

References:

1. [AGE Python Driver](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/master/drivers/python)
2. [AGE Python Driver Sample File](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/python/samples/apache-age-note.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Considering a snippet of your code below;

```
arrival_time = edges[i].properties('arrival_time').value
departure_time = edges[i].properties('departure_time').value
next_departure_time = edges[i+1].properties('departure_time').value
```

you are accessing the values of the property as a python dictionary but **an edge in AGE is not a python datatype but of AGE agtype**.

Hence the right way to access the values of properties of an edge follows the standard `edges[index][property_name]`.

Therefore the code snippet I referenced earlier should be:

```
arrival_time = edges[i]['arrival_time']
departure_time = edges[i]['departure_time']
next_departure_time = edges[i+1]['departure_time']
```